# Prove $ \frac{3}{1-\sin^6x-\cos^6x}=(\tan x + \cot x)^2$.

Tags: trigonometry

$$ \frac{3}{1-\sin^6x-\cos^6x}=(\tan x + \cot x)^2$$
Need help with an identity I got for my high school homework. Can't seem to find a way to prove it. Please help with easiest way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I feel I had to flag this. This isn't a site that will solve your homework for you, and some effort or examples of your own thoughts must be shown. That way, we can help you—and others—the best we can. For more information, please read [how to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) and [How to ask a homework question?](https://goo.gl/Fyfb22). At any rate, I wish the best of luck to you, and please continue to contribute to our wonderful site!

Comment: Before we can help, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I always do my homework by myself. I don't use the site for people to do homework for me... Whats the point of that? What knowledge do I get from that? I only refer to this site when I am stumped and really have no idea how to solve a problem.

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) and [How to ask a homework question?](https://goo.gl/Fyfb22), as previously mentioned.

Comment: If I had any good ideas I would of wrote them... I am stumped really and don't know where to start. Why the hate?
The right side is easy and is obviously $\tan^2x+2+\cot^2x$
The left side on the other hand... Am I allowed to isolate $1^3$ ?

Comment: How can you factorise $s^6+c^6$ ?

Comment: How do I get $s^6+c^6$?

Answer (score 1):

The RHS reads

$$\left(\frac sc+\frac cs\right)^2=\frac{1^2}{c^2s^2}$$ hints you to rework the denominator of the LHS.

Terms $s^6+c^6$ can appear from the development of

$$1^3=(s^2+c^2)^3=s^6+3s^4c^2+3s^2c^4+c^6=s^6+c^6+3s^2c^2.$$

The rest is easy.

Comment: How did you get this ?

Comment: @RiktasMath: reduce to the common denominator and simplify.

Comment: Well then wouldn't it be $s^4 + c^4$ on top? Not $s^2+c^2$ ?

Comment: @RiktasMath: no.

Comment: $(\frac{s}{c}+\frac{c}{s})^2 = (\frac{c^2+s^2}{sc})^2 = (\frac{1}{sc})^2 = \frac{1}{(sc)^2} = \frac{1}{s^2c^2}$ For the second part, $3s^4c^2+3s^2c^4 = 3s^2c^2(s^2+c^2) = 3s^2c^2(1)$

Comment: Thanks @woogie. Can you explain how he gets $s^6+c^6+3s^2c^2$ from this ?

Comment: He makes use of a very convenient theorem called the Binomial Theorem, which gives the expansion of $$(x+y)^n$$ for any positive integer $n$. In the denominator, when you replace $1$ with $s^6+c^6+3s^2c^2$ they get cancelled out with the $-s^6-c^6$ that were already there on the LHS.

Comment: I know it but I have: $ \frac{3}{s^6+3s^2c^2+c^6}.$ I need to make it $ \frac{1}{c^2s^2}$

Comment: I don't get how 1 can be replaced by $s^2+c^2$

Comment: $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x=1$ is a trig identity itself. Since it is always true for any value of x, we're free to exchange it wherever we need to.

Comment: True. Thats interesting!. But how does 1 become $1^3$ on the LHS ?

Comment: $1^3=1$. $$1^n=1$$

Comment: I FINISHED IT! Thank you @woogie! You have saved me from not sleeping all night! Thank you soooo much! God bless, all the best!